# Missing \endgroup inserted at start of mdframed environment

Tags: mdframed

For the life of me I can't figure out why I am getting this error.  I've scoured the documentation for the `mdframed` package and cant figure it out.

Here is a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
Prior text
\begin{mdframed}[]
Some Text
\end{mdframed}  
El fin.
\end{document}
```

I get a series of errors when I compile it.  What I think are the pertinent parts of the output are as follows:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350) system commands enabled.
(test3.tex
.... {skipped lines}
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]
                    Some Text\end{mdframed}
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]
                    Some Text\end{mdframed}
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]
                    Some Text\end{mdframed}
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
\endgroup 
l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]
                    Some Text\end{mdframed}
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]
                    Some Text\end{mdframed}
! Extra \endgroup.
\needspace ...p -\dimen@ \vskip \z@skip \endgroup 

l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]
                    Some Text\end{mdframed}
! Extra \endgroup.
\color@endgroup ->\endgraf \endgroup 

l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]Some Text\end{mdframed}


! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{mdframed}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]Some Text\end{mdframed}

! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.6 \begin{mdframed}[]Some Text\end{mdframed}

! Extra \endgroup.
\color@endgroup ->\endgraf \endgroup 

l.8 \end{document}

! Too many }'s.
\endsa@boxit ...dvarwidth \color@endgroup \egroup 

l.8 \end{document}
```

I have tried it with xelatex and pdflatex (removing the first line of the MWE) and I get the same errors.

Is this a recent bug in `mdframed` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you have wants to make paragraphs, which are not allowed with `standalone`. Unfortunately, the `varwidth` option doesn't work, but `preview` does.

You get no error with a different document class.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[preview,border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
Prior text
\begin{mdframed}[]
Some Text
\end{mdframed}
El fin.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  I guess I should have read the standalone documentation in addition to the mdframed documentation.  Thank you.